# What happens when data is loaded into Scala Spark and there is integer overflow?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How will Scala/Spark handle loading data that is larger than its assigned type in a schema? I.e. if I define a column with `IntegerType` but load a number from an external dataset larger than Scala's `int` will the program fail or will the data just be dropped?

Comment: Why not test by yourself ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this out to get the answer.

##### Test Data

```sh
name,id
"one",1234
"two",123456789
"three",1234567890123456123456789
```

##### Reading Data

```scala
val schema = new StructType().add("name", StringType).add("id", IntegerType)
val test = spark.read.option("header", "true").schema(schema).csv("test.csv")
```

##### Resulting read

```scala
test.show()

+----+---------+
|name|       id|
+----+---------+
| one|     1234|
| two|123456789|
|null|     null|
+----+---------+


test.printSchema()

root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
```

So since the data was an integer type, the resulting data row ended up getting read as null, instead of failing.

##### Non-Nullable Field?

If the field in a schema cannot be null, it will still end up reading the data as null.

```scala
val schema2 = new StructType().add("name", StringType).add("id", IntegerType, false)

val test2 = spark.read...
:
:
test2.show()
+----+---------+
|name|       id|
+----+---------+
| one|     1234|
| two|123456789|
|null|     null|
+----+---------+

test2.printSchema()
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
```

My understanding here is that spark would rather assume that it's a nullable field when it sees data it can't read, even if it is specified as a non-nullable field in the schema. This way, spark reads the entire data rather than fail on runtime.